# QAF: API ERROR code 0x80072530 : Passed entity object cannot be null or empty

Tags: java, json, ntlm, qaf

Implementing the NTLMAutClient is working with valid ntlm credentials. However, upon running the JSON request, the aforementioned error occurs.

Below is the JSON payload:

```json
{
    "headers":
    {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    
    "endPoint": "",
    "baseUrl": "${crm_base_url}/api/data/v9.1/contacts(mli_integrationkey='CAS-${clientNumber}')",
    "method": "PATCH",
    
    "body":
    {
        "mli_mcfuserid": ""
    }
}
```

And here is the response from the QMetry report:

**Request**

> Client out-bound request
> PATCH [https://baseurl.com/CRM/api/data/v9.1/contacts(mli_integrationkey='CAS-1234567890')](https://baseurl.com/CRM/api/data/v9.1/contacts(mli_integrationkey=%27CAS-1234567890%27))
> Content-Type: application/json
> {"mli_mcfuserid":""}

**Response**

> Client in-bound response
> 400
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> Allow: OPTIONS,GET,HEAD,POST
> Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
> Expires: -1
> Server:
> x-ms-service-request-id: 8e609396-690e-44f4-8d9a-2cf2d423856e
> Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
> REQ_ID: 8e609396-690e-44f4-8d9a-2cf2d423856e
> REQ_ID: 8e609396-690e-44f4-8d9a-2cf2d423856e
> Set-Cookie: ReqClientId=20330979-0d93-47d0-bd2b-0313bef1fb24; expires=Fri, 19-Jan-2074 10:46:11 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
> Set-Cookie: orgId=f1983a41-2ae6-e811-8120-0050568b693f; expires=Fri, 19-Jan-2074 10:46:11 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
> OData-Version: 4.0
> Persistent-Auth: true
> Public: OPTIONS,GET,HEAD,POST
> Timing-Allow-Origin: *
> Date: Fri, 19 Jan 2024 10:46:10 GMT
> Content-Length: 89

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "0x80072530",
        "message": "Passed entity object cannot be null or empty."
    }
}
```

Already tried a lot of debugging like updating the **qaf-support-ws** version, using different ntlm credentials (with and without the ntlm.workstation and ntlm.domain), trying different headers combinations, etc., but still stuck with the error.

**[UPDATE]**
Below is the method we use to read and execute .json payload files:

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    File file = new File(path);
    Object data = jsonParser.parse(new FileReader(file));
    JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().toJsonTree(data).getAsJsonObject();
    HashMap<String, Object> result;
    
    try {
        result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonObject.toString(), HashMap.class);
        RestRequestBean bean = new RestRequestBean();
        bean.fillData(jsonObject.toString());
        bean.resolveParameters(result);
        return WsStep.request(bean);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        logger.info("JsonParseException: ", e);
    } catch (JsonMappingException f) {
        logger.info("JsonParseException: ", f);
    } catch (IOException g) {
        logger.info("JsonParseException: ", g);
    }
```

**Dependencies version:**

> **qaf:** 3.0.0
>
> **qaf-support-ws:** 2.1.13
>
> **quantum-version:** 1.23.0

Comment: It looks server responded with the error. What response you are expecting? Is it same using curl?

Comment: @user861594, the response code is **400**, so it is likely not a server-side error. I use Postman and the request works fine. It is just I can't make it work in QAF.

Answer (score 0):

If body is json you still need to quote it. For example:

```
"body": "{ \"mli_mcfuserid\": \"\"}"
```

You also can use [repository editor](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/repo_editor.html) to avid syntax issues and to manually try before using request call in automation. For web service calls, if your file has `.properties` extension, change it to `.wsc` and you will be able to create/edit/execute through ui.

Comment: Our project is in Java and that's how our .json files are constructed. Also, I am using **JSON Editor plugin** that checks such files for syntax errors.

Comment: Did you tried quoting json value for body? Body is expected to be string not json object in qaf request call, so if you are providing valid json, editor may not complain syntax error but possibly result in bad request. If you use repor-editor, you will see body without quote but saved value will have quotes.

Comment: I got the idea to remove the request body's content in Postman, and it returned the same error, then thought probably you were right, so I followed the same format on your answer but sadly, the same error occurred.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, by the way. I added updates to my problem that might give further ideas why it is happening.

Comment: I would suggest you to try with latest version of qaf and qaf support ws library. Like I mentioned in answer, try with repo-editor just like you tried in postman. If it works with repo-editor, same is used in automation.